# How to set-up a cross-sectional regression with common shocks?

Tags: regression, econometrics, cross-section

Let's assume we have a response vector $y$ with "n" observations, and two predictors $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Let's take an example: Let y be the crime rate in 48 states, and $X_1$ = National GDP rate, $X_2$ = National Unemployment rate. Note that the value of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is constant for all the states.

I would like to evaluate whether $X_1$ and $X_2$, here US GDP and US Unemployment Rate, help explain the cross-sectional difference in crime rates between the 48 states. This is what is commonly known as a cross-sectional regression with common shocks. The impact of common shocks typically is not the same across different population units. For example, a stock market shock affects wealthy individuals much more than poor individuals. An oil price shock affects airlines and auto companies much more than computer companies.

So, how can I run the cross-sectional regression with two common shocks $X_1$ and $X_2$?  The following set-up is not possible:

$$Y = \beta_1 X_1 + \beta_21 X_2 + \epsilon$$

since the dimensions do not match. The dimensions are: $dim(Y)$ is (48x1), $dim(X_1)$ is 1, $dim(X_2)$ is 1.

How can I set-up the regression then? Could you please help?

Thank you,

Comment: Cross-sectional regression with common _shocks_ usually refers to the full or partial commonality of _shocks_, i.e. of $\epsilon$ in your notation - not in the commonality of _regressors_. Look it up. Apart from that , your problem is not one of dimensionality but one of invertibility: you cannot have more than one constant regressors in the same regressor matrix, it becomes singular and the LS estimator cannot be calculated (except if you want to go for a generalized inverse, if that would be meaningful in your set up).

Comment: Thanks for your post. My question is then: how do you treat such a problem?

Comment: This is a whole model, too long to be fully presented here. You should look up available expositions. I don't know what your level in econometrics is, but one recent reference is cowles.econ.yale.edu/P/cp/p11b/p1153.pdf‎. The invertibility issue can only be solved if you can obtain panel data (so you will have common regressors alright, but variability along the time axis) -but I have already answered this part in another question of yours.